# Imprima "n" números ímpares naturais

Tags: python

Estou resolvendo um exercício que pede para que eu digite um valor por exemplo: 5 e imprima os 5 primeiros números ímpares naturais no caso:

entrada:

Digite o valor de n: 5

- 1
- 3
- 5
- 7
- 9

O código que escrevi funciona porém não me parece a melhor lógica para resolução do mesmo. Alguém saberia alguma outra solução "simples" porque estou aprendendo ainda

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))

i = 1

while i <= (n+n):
if i % 2 != 0:
    print(i)
    i += 1
else:
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consegui entender e aplicar com outra lógica sem precisar somar *n+n*, no caso ficaria desta maneira:

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))

i = 0
ímpar = 1

while i < n: 
  print(ímpar)
  i = i + 1
  ímpar = ímpar + 2
```

Answer (score 6):

Uma alternativa bem simples seria com a função `range(start, stop, step)`

- Start: número inicial da sequência.
- Stop: até este número, mas não o inclui na sequência.
- Step: diferença entre cada número na sequência.

  ```
  n = int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))
  for i in range(1, n+n, 2):
     print(i)
  ```

output:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Agradeço mano @Mathias

Answer (score 1):

Fiz dessa forma no Python, que inclui o último número se for ímpar.

```
num = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))

for num in range(1, num+1, 2):

    print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Também é possível solucionar o problema sem utilizar qualquer tipo de laço de iteração, apenas desempacotando os valores da [sequencia](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), gerada com [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-range), usando o [operador *](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=unpack#unpacking-argument-lists) e os passando como argumentos para função [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print).

No exemplo separador, parâmetro `sep`, será um caractere *newline*:

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))
print(*range(1, 2*n, 2), sep="\n")
```

Resultado:

```
Digite o valor de n: 5
1
3
5
7
9
```

Outra abordagem manipulando os argumentos de `print()` pode ser obtida combinando a função  dos números naturais impares ***f(x) = 2x + 1 | x ∈ N*** dentro duma [compreensão de lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions)

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))
print(*[2*x+1 for x in range(n)], sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para deixar registrada outra alternativa (e admito que talvez seja meio *overkill*, já que as demais soluções com `range` são mais simples), você pode usar o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import islice, count

n = int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))
for i in islice(count(1, 2), n):
    print(i)
```

Primeiro, [`count(1, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) retorna um iterador que começa em 1, pulando de 2 em 2 (assim, eu garanto que ele só tem números ímpares, e sempre começando do `1`). A seguir, [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) recebe este iterador e pega os primeiros `n` elementos dele.

O resultado são os primeiros `n` números ímpares.

Comment: Também dá para fazer usando o repeat `for i in repeat(count(1, 2), 5): print(next(i))`.

Answer (score 0):

Para se obter os 5 primeros números ímpares:

```
    n = int(input("Digite o valor de n:"))

    # Inicializações
    i = 0 # Contador
    r = 1 # Resultado

    # Imprima os números ímpares
    while i < n:
       i += 1
       print(r)
       r += 2
```

Answer (score -5):

Pode utilizar o ciclo for, que gosto bastante:

```
printf("Digite o numero");
int k = scanf(&k);

for(int x = 0; x < k; k++){
if(k%2 != 0){
printf("%i\n", k);
} // end if
} // end for
```

Comment: Por favor, atente-se a todas informações da pergunta antes de responder. Foi solicitado ajuda na linguagem Python, portanto sua resposta não atende às necessidades.