# Como contar quantos números ímpares há entre -999 e 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso fazer um algoritmo que me informe quantos números impares há entre -999 e 0

Exemplo: entre esses valores a n números impares

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Imprima "n" números ímpares naturais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197437/imprima-n-n%c3%bameros-%c3%admpares-naturais)

Comment: n%2 == 0 é par,se for 1 é impar. Faça essa lógica. Agora em Python não sei se suporta este operador.

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um exercício de Progressão Aritmética também conhecida como *PA*.

Uma progressão aritmética é uma sequência numérica em que cada termo, a partir do segundo, é igual à soma do termo anterior com uma constante *r*. O número *r* é chamado de razão ou diferença comum da progressão aritmética.

A fórmula do termo geral de uma Progressão Aritmética é dada por:

> **an = a1 + (n - 1).r**

onde:

> **an** = último termo da sequencia.
>
> **a1** = primeiro termo da sequencia.
>
> **n** = quantidade de termos na sequencia.
>
> **r** = razão da sequencia.

Para essa questão vamos usar a fórmula da quantidade de termos de uma PA que é determinada por:

> **n = (an - a1)/r + 1**

Então para obter a quantidade de números primos entre -999 e 0 basta substituir os valores conhecidos na fórmula e encontrar *n*.

Com para obter um novo número ímpar devemos somar 2 ao ímpar anterior:

> 1 + 2 = 3
>
> 3 + 2 = 5
>
> 5 + 2 = 7

Implicando que razão de sua sequencia, ou *r*, é 2. 
Como você quer calcular a quantidade de números ímpares a série considerada deve começar com o primeiro número e o último ímpar da sua sequencia.Então:

> an = -1
>
> a1 = -999
>
> r  = 2

Portanto:

> **n = (-1 - (-999))/2 + 1 -> n = 998/2 + 1 -> n = 499 + 1 => n = 500**

Aplicando esse raciocínio em Python:

```
#Lê o primeiro termo da PA
a1 = int(input("Digite o valor do primeiro termo: "))
#lê o último termo da PA
an = int(input("Digite o valor do último termo: "))

#Verifica se a sequencia é crescente ou decrescente 
#e procura o primeiro e último ímpar do intervalo
if (an >= a1):
  if (a1 % 2 == 0): a1 += 1
  if (an % 2 == 0): an -= 1
  #Ajusta a razão pra série crescente
  r = 2
else:
  if (a1 % 2 == 0): a1 -= 1
  if (an % 2 == 0): an += 1
  #Ajusta a razão pra série decrescente
  r = -2

#Calcula o número de termos da PA
n = (an - a1)//r + 1

#Exibe o resultado
print('Existem ' + str(n) + ' ímpar(es) nesse intervalo.')
```

[Código funcionando Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/QuixoticHandmadeDemand)

Answer (score 0):

Esse é um exercício básico, pratique.

```py
c = 0
for i in range(-999, 0):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        c += 1
print(c)

########OUTPUT########
500
```

Comment: o correto seria: `for i in range(-999, 1):`

Comment: @LuizAugusto Como zero é par, tanto faz ele estar ou não no `range` (se fosse um algoritmo que recebe quaisquer números, de fato o certo seria `range(inicio, fim + 1)`, mas como ele pediu números específicos, não faz diferença). Mas na verdade, se eu só quero os ímpares, use `range(-999, 0, 2)` para pular os pares. Mas se esse range só tem ímpares, pra que testar `% 2`? Faça logo `len(range(-999, 0, 2))` :-)  Ok, sei que *provavelmente* é um exercício e o professor *provavelmente* quer que faça o loop "tradicional" de um em um, mas achei que valia a pena mencionar as alternativas... :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo exato, depois observei que o 1 ou 0 não fariam diferença para o exercício proposto, mas acredito que ficou válido mencionar já que o professor poderia pergunta algo do tipo.